# Twitter Oauth Strategy with Warden + Devise Authentication Gems for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, oauth, devise

Devise, the authentication gem for Ruby based on Warden (another auth gem) does not support Twitter Oauth as an authentication strategy, BUT Warden does. There is a way to use the Warden Twitter Oauth strategy within Devise, but I cannot figure it out. I'm using the following block in the devise config file:

```
  config.warden do |manager|
       manager.oauth(:twitter) do |twitter|
          twitter.consumer_secret = <SECRET>
          twitter.consumer_key  = <KEY>
          twitter.options :site => 'http://twitter.com'
       end
       manager.default_strategies.unshift :twitter_oauth
  end
```

But I keep on getting all sorts of error messages. Does anyone know how to make this work? I'm assuming there is more to do here (configuring a new link/route to talk to Warden, maybe adding attributes to the Devise User model, etc.), but I can't figure out what they are. Please help.

Comment: Hey, do you solve the problem? I'm looking for the same solution

Comment: I actually didn't. I'm temporarily using a version of mbleigh's twitter_auth gem instead.

Comment: Devise 1.2.rc support now omniauth. I think can really help you to fix you problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Needed gems. Add to your Gemfile if you are using Rails3.  
gem 'devise'
gem 'warden_oauth'

#models/user.rb
devise :token_authenticatable, :oauthable # <-- Must have these

#/config/initializers/devise.rb
require 'warden_oauth'
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.oauth(:twitter) do |twitter|
    twitter.consumer_secret = '<SECRET>'
    twitter.consumer_key  = '<CONSUMER KEY>'
    twitter.options :site => 'http://twitter.com'
  end
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :twitter_oauth
end

Warden::OAuth.access_token_user_finder(:twitter) do |access_token|
  User.find_or_create_by(:token => access_token.token, :secret => access_token.secret).tap do |user|
    #... 
  end
end

# Link to "Login With Twitter" somewhere in your view
<%= link_to( "Login With Twitter", user_session_path(:warden_oauth_provider => 'twitter') ) %>
```

Comment: Quick question... is oauthable compatible with 1.0 (for rails 2.x) or do you need 1.1 (rails 3)?

Comment: It seems OAuth support was added to 1.1 so you may need to be on Rails 3.

Comment: Note: this only works for Oauth2 (Facebook, Git), and not Twitter (Oauth 1.0).

Comment: Strange all i get is: authenticate! is not declared in the :twitter_oauth strategy

Answer (score 3):

[Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) makes this easy. There is a Railscast on using Omniauth with Devise ([part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1), [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)).

Answer (score 0):

This solution *does* work. You just have to make sure that you're calling a protected action when specifying :warden_oauth_provider => 'twitter', otherwise Rails will simply ignore it.

To use the example above, change the link to:

```
<%= link_to( "Login With Twitter", user_session_path(:warden_oauth_provider => 'twitter'), :method => :post ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you define a class or a module named Twitter (you can check this by running script/console then type Twitter), if you did, name it to something non-existent.